# How can we filter data in sqlite through database through date?

Tags: android, sqlite

just straight forward question.
I have date details of items stored in sqlite in epoch format of time.
Now i want to filter it so that i can get only data before 5 day of it. How can i do that. Can you please give me a detail answer?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that SQLite has a native GETDATE() function. I think you should be able to filter based on your date column, even if it is text. For example, if your date column is called item_date, you can query like so:

```
select * from <yourtable> where item_date between 'CurrentDate-5' and 'CurrentDate'
```

Just set some variables before hand a pass them in to the above query.

Comment: The date that is stored in my column is in epoch format i.e. its some what like this 15938594839 which has value of both date and time.

Comment: Then convert the parameters in the same format as your stored value before passing them to your query

Comment: I agree with @F0r3v3r-A-N00b. You know the format. Create some type of method that gets the current date and current date - 5 days in the correct format and pass it in that query.